# How to compile this fortan program?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, compiling

My cousin is a phd student required to install this [software](https://stockage.univ-brest.fr/~grima/Ariane/ariane_install_2.x.x_sep08.pdf) on his ubuntu 16.04. He didn't know how to do it, asked my help, but I've never worked with fortan before. We installed both gcc and gfortan.

As shown in the pdf, we must run:

```
./configure # this complains about the absence of netcdf
make
make check
make install
```

I kept getting `netCDF` errors. Found [this](https://gist.github.com/perrette/cd815d03830b53e24c82) and now I'm getting this error when running configure

```
Can't find libnetcdf.a in /usr/lib
```

I spent like 5h trying to fix it, searching for everything, no luck.

Update: I did what [Nicolas suggested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqSvU.jpg), still [there's an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYeIm.jpg).

Comment: Does the student have the `libnetcdff6` package installed? If the script installed elsewhere you may have to move the library file around

Comment: Alternately you could just install the `libnetcdff6` package from apt.

Comment: I haven't downloaded the software (it appears to require registration) however maybe the issue is that your libnetcdf only provides the shared library - not the static (`.a`) lib. Maybe there's a configuration setting to force dynamic linking? (try running `./configure --help` and examining the output for words like `static` and/or `shared`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the developer of the software mentioned above by Lynob (Lagrangian analysis tool named [Ariane](http://stockage.univ-brest.fr/~grima/Ariane/ariane.html)).

As mentioned by steeldriver the problem is due to the lack of the static netcdf library (*.a) for the Fortran interface of NetCDF in Ubuntu 16.04.

I made a bug report about this problem here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netcdf/+bug/1698368.

To solve the problem:

- be sure that netcdf library is intalled (`ls -rtl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*netcdf*`)
- be sure that netcdff is also
  installed (`ls -rtl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*netcdf*`)
- download the last version of the Ariane software: Ariane-v2.2.9_00.tar.gz (http://stockage.univ-brest.fr/~grima/Ariane/download/download.html).

After decompressing the package, then submit:

```
./configure 
make 
make check 
make install
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/usFKGMR and https://imgur.com/bGm1PM7 
Click on any of them to zoom in, I have the libraries installed, the problem is still there

Comment: although it didn't work on my pc, it worked on my cousin's pc and he's the one who needs ariane. Thank you